# string conversion and then difference between int and int converted string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pyspark

i am trying to get the century from a 13 digit ID number, so far my approach is like this:

```
def verrify_age(string):
    new_id = ''.join(('19', string))
    new_id = new_id[:4]
    year = int(new_id)

    curr_year = datetime.date.today().year

    if year < curr_year:
        return 'alive'
    else:
        return 'possibly dead'
```

From the above code i'm joining str('19) to the id number e.g '19'+ string =['9507015312086'] making it '199507015312086', then slice the 1st 4 digits(1994) and convert that to int. the idea is to check difference between: 1994< 2020 which gives the error:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '19E0'

Comment: base 16 and `19ZEP0139726HH`; - can you explain what should happen?

Comment: Why do you trying to parse the string by hexadecimal?

Comment: And according to your error message, your ID includes non-digits.

Comment: When i test it on dummy string it works, when converting the function to a UDF and populating a new column in my data frame that's when the error occurs. i am basically trying to figure out the full year from a person's ID number

Comment: basically my idear after many attempts is to determine the century of the ID number. so i envisioned adding a string '19' to the original ID number which is in string type  in the DF

Comment: Please provide the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Your description is inconsistent with your code; you have values other than a direct string concatenation, and what you say is your attempt to extract the year, makes no logical sense.

Comment: DO: add 19 to the beggining of IDnumber to form 199505013425086, then slice the year off the new ID number, and compare that year to the current date.year() to check if ID number is valid. The ID number in the df are string based, idea is to convert the added 2 digits to string then int() so that i can perform the checks as integers.

Comment: i basically want to check from the id number if someone is still living or dead by the birth year. but ID numbers have 93-03-12 and i want to add those 2 prefix digits to form 1993-03-12 and then use that 1993 with the current year

Comment: verrify_age('9505013425086')                                                                                                                     expected results: (1995, 'alive')                                                                                                               but when i run it through a udf for the purpose of df.withColumn('status', verrify_age(f.col(id_number)))                                                                                                                     thats when it fails

Comment: i managed to get it...but it discriminates those date of births that are 2000, cant replicate with '19' + 00 which definitely be too old. so now i have to find a formula to get exact centuries for each **00 birth year.

Comment: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '19E0'` This occurs because the first 2 characters of `string` are `E0`. You're going have to clean your data if you want to reliably use that technique.

Comment: i did manage to get the result, thanks